# Match variables inside string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match variables inside a string, which are addressed using the dollar symbol `$`. However, my regex expression should *not* match character sequences following an escaped dollar symbol (e.g. escaped with the backslash `\$`).
If a backslash is escaped with an other one (`\\`), the following variable should of course be matched.

**TL;DR**: Any sequence `$xxxxx`should be matched, **only** if it follows a even count of backslashes `\` (0, 2, 4, 6, ...). The backslashes themselves should **not** be part of the capture group.

---

I currently have the following expression: `(?:[^\\]*(\\{2})*)(\$[a-z_]\w*\b)`,
but it does not work correctly on the following text (of course with the options `\igm`):

```
Hello $var, this is a backslash followed by a dollar: \\\$
$test \$escaped \\$not_escaped \\\$escaped_again \\\\$you_get_the_idea
```

The matched 'variables' should be `$var`, `$test`, `$not_escaped` and `$you_get_the_idea`.

However, https://regex101.com displays other matches.

---

I cannot get my head around the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this regex with a lookbehind assertion, you can capture the variable strings in group 1:

```
(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*(\$\w+)
```

[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/T0ieaQ/2)

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. Your Regex did the job perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

With some extra logic in C# you can use this regex:

```
(?<esc>\\*)\$(?<var>\w+)
```

it will capture in two groups - first for backslashes and second for variable name. Now you only need to throw away matches with odd length in first group. Try this code:

```
var regex = new Regex("(?<esc>\\\\*)\\$(?<var>\\w+)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
var text = "Hello $var, this is a backslash $ followed by a dollar: \\\\\\$\r\n$test \\$escaped \\\\$not_escaped \\\\\\$escaped_again \\\\\\\\$you_get_the_idea";
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
{
    if (match.Groups["esc"].Length % 2 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["var"].Value);
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5oP9O4)

Comment: Thank you for your proposition, however, the pure regex solution is more elegant for my use case.

Answer (score -1):

You can simple try this regex:- 
[\$][\w]*

Comment: How will it recognize a leading backslash? `$var` will be matched by your expression, but so will be `\$var`, which **should not** be matched

Comment: No leading backslash won't be matched by this regex, it's just an escape sequence for $, so that it would not be treated as a wild character

Comment: I am sorry, I did not make myself clear enough: the substring `$var` should **only** be matched if it is directly following an even count of backslashes (0, 2, 4, 6, ...). The backslashes themselves should of course not be part of the capture group